# likert error If trying to subset a data frame to analyze only one column

Tags: r, statistics, likert

This is my data frame that's I'm working for.

Satisf <- likert(as.data.frame(Dataset_clean[ , 16]), grouping = Dataset$`Qual é o seu grupo de idade?`)

likert.bar.plot(Satisf,legend = "Legenda")

Dataset_clean[16]
Em geral, qual o seu nível de satisfação profissional?
1                                              Satisfeito
2                                              Satisfeito
3                                              Satisfeito
4                                            Insatisfeito
5                                            Insatisfeito
6                                            Insatisfeito
7                                            Insatisfeito
8                                            Insatisfeito

Dataset[8]
Qual é o seu grupo de idade?
1        Geração Z (18-24 anos)
2        Geração Z (18-24 anos)
3        Geração Z (18-24 anos)
4        Geração Z (18-24 anos)
5        Geração Z (18-24 anos)
6        Geração Z (18-24 anos)
7        Geração Z (18-24 anos)
8        Geração Z (18-24 anos)

I'm trying to create a plot with one column, but I'm getting in trouble.

```
Likert cannot handle with one column if and plot  Dataset_clean[12:16]
```

I dont know how to edit column name that appear in the graph with a name Dataset_clean[ , 16]

```
Error in likert(Satisf, grouping = Dataset_clean$`Qual é o seu grupo de idade?`) : 
  The items parameter must be a data frame. If trying to subset a data frame to analyze only one column, try: items=mydf[,1, drop=FALSE].
```

Should be a bug?:
This check should probably just be is.data.frame(). Perhaps it can be reported at https://github.com/jbryer/likert/issues?

It looks like it's fixed in the latest development version though: https://github.com/jbryer/likert/blob/master/R/likert.R#L71-L75

[image]

Anyone knows how to edit $data$item [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kdOV.png)

Maybe is the problem:
Satisf[["data"]][["Item"]]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQFoo.png) Dataset_clean[, 16] Dataset_clean[, 16] Dataset_clean[, 16] Dataset_clean[, 16] Dataset_clean[, 16]
[6] Dataset_clean[, 16] Dataset_clean[, 16] Dataset_clean[, 16]
Levels: Dataset_clean[, 16]

Comment: What package is `likert()` from? Also, a reproducible example would go a long way to helping.

Comment: Documentation for package ‘likert’ version 1.3.5

Comment: RStudio
Version 1.3.1093
© 2009-2020 RStudio, PBC Operation system windows 10

Comment: RStudio has nothing to do with your issue. And it's not possible to help you without understanding your data.

Comment: I got the solution: Basically I renamed items and recode results$Item.
Satisf$items <- rename(Satisf$items, replace = c("Dataset_clean[, 16]" = "Satisfação"))
Satisf$results$Item <- recode_factor(Satisf$results$Item, "Dataset_clean[, 16]" = "Satisfação")